# Problem with MongoDB service error on MacOS12.6 Monterey

Tags: mongodb, elixir, phoenix-framework

I've just upgraded to MacOS 12.6 and my Elixir/Phoenix app is no longer able to connect to MongoDB. When I start Phoenix I get the following error:

```
13:00:40.900 [error] Mongo.Protocol (#PID<0.439.0>) failed to connect: ** (Mongo.Error) tcp connect: connection refused - :econnrefused
```

When I run `brew services` I get the following output:

```
Name              Status      User File
dbus              none             
mongodb-community error  3584      /usr/local/opt/mongodb-community/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
postgresql@14     none
```

I'm assuming the reason my phoenix app can no longer connect to MongoDB is due to the `error` listed under the `Status` heading, and I have no idea how to troubleshoot this.

I've searched around but am now completely stuck. Has anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: are you sure that mongo is running?  A good check is always to try logging into mongo via the command line and see if you can connect and get to the mongo prompt.

Comment: No it doesn't appear that mongo is running, probably due to the `error` status that is listed when I `brew services`. I've no idea how to troubleshoot this. I've tried uninstalling and re-installing with `brew` but I simply end up in the same situation.

Comment: If the `brew` message is relevant, then there must be a log file somewhere that would contain more info.  If you're running `mongo` locally, you start the server process using `mongod`, e.g. `mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf` 
You may want to explore running `mongo` via docker, e.g. `docker pull mongo` then `docker run --name mongo -p 27017:27017 -d mongo`, but as before, nothing works unless you start the process, e.g. `docker start mongo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging around it looks like Homebrew upgraded my MongoDB by at least 1 major version. The upgrade caused an upgrade to the WiredTiger storage engine which meant that all my data files that had been written by the earlier version were out of sync with what the new version of WiredTiger was expecting - which was causing MongoDB to error on start up.

The solution was to remove the data directory, and create a new empty one.